# Force.com IDE Required field is missing: encodingKey

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide, required-field

I successfully deployed my files to the Salesforce server yesterday but today, I got a "Required field is missing: encodingKey."

It says the Resource is .DS_Store and the path is leading to the email templates that I have. The type is a "Force.com save problem."

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you including meta.xml file while doing deployment for Email Template Component?

Comment: Sounds like a hidden Mac file that shouldn't have been deployed in the first place.

Comment: Can you share your `package.xml` file?

Comment: For some reason, I refreshed the project and the error went away. Not sure why but thanks for the responses!